# How to refresh contents of a tree when using Angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a sample of a tree-view using Angularjs directive in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4XDbpDV7E2nahzSgHsZZ?p=preview).

Part of the code:

```
.directive('treeView', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      value: '=',
      key: '=',
      filter: '=',
      idx: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var value = scope.value
      scope.curValue = scope.value;
      console.log(scope.curValue)

      var template =
        '<ul>' +
          '<li>{{key}}</li>' +
          '<li class="inner-node" ng-repeat="(k,v) in curValue">' +
            '<i class="collapsed" ng-show="haschildren(v)" ng-class="{\'list-plus\':!k' + "open" + '}" ng-click="k' + "open" + '=!k' + "open" + '"></i>' +
            '<span class="" ng-click="seeAll(k)">{{k}}</span>' +
          '</li>' +
        '</ul>';
      scope.haschildren = function(obj) {
        return !$.isEmptyObject(obj)
      };
      scope.seeAll = function(key) {};
      element.html('').append($compile(template)(scope));
    }
  };
}]);
```

I want to change tree nodes by click switch button which set scope.fields a new value.

But after click there is nothing changed.
I think it was because I use link method in a wrong way, but I don't know what the right way is.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the link function is executed once, when the directive is first linked.

You should use the template property of the directive to set the template. After that, you could put the scope.hasChildren and scope.seeAll methods in a controller for the directive.

Check the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SDXAHJCMSRNaumGd1xCk?p=preview).

```
.directive('treeView', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      value: '=',
      key: '=',
      filter: '=',
      idx: '='
    },
    template: '<ul>' +
        '<li>{{key}}</li>' +
        '<li class="inner-node" ng-repeat="(k,v) in value">' +
        '<i class="collapsed" ng-show="haschildren(v)" ng-class="{\'list-plus\':!k' + "open" + '}" ng-click="k' + "open" + '=!k' + "open" + '"></i>' +
        '<span class="" ng-click="seeAll(k)">{{k}}</span>' +
        '</li>' +
        '</ul>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    },
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.haschildren = function(obj) {
        return !$.isEmptyObject(obj)
      };
      $scope.seeAll = function(key) {};

    }
  };
}]);
```